# codeigniter auto increment foreignkey

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert, auto-increment

In my application i have function to insert data to mysqldb and have more one image for one news and in database I make news id as foreign key in upload table and all inserts is work fine but the problem news FK in upload table when i insert data the first row inserted take the value i set it and the other take auto increment so the next you found code :

the inserted data in upload table
[image: upload table data]

as you se the correct data is row have id 31 and the other is auto increment 

the code I insert by him ;

the controller

```
    public function insertNews() {
    $this->do_one_upload();
        $this->load->model('newsModel');
        $this->load->model('fileModel');
        $ad_ne_data = array(
                'titel' => $this->input->post('ad_news_title') ,
                'content' => $this->input->post('ad_news_content') ,
                'news_category_id' => $this->input->post('ad_news_category') ,
                'img_url' => $this->do_one_upload()[1]['full_path'],
                'created_at' => date("Y-m-d")
        );

        $this->newsModel->addNews($ad_ne_data);
        $i=0;
        while($i < count($this->do_one_upload())) {
            // var_dump($this->do_one_upload());
            $ad_imgs_news =array(
                'title' => $this->do_one_upload()[$i]['client_name'],
                'file_path' => $this->do_one_upload()[$i]['full_path'],
                'type' => $this->do_one_upload()[$i]['file_type'],
                'size' => $this->do_one_upload()[$i]['file_size'],
                'img_news_id' => $this->newsModel->getLastNewsId()
            );
             $i++;
            $this->fileModel->addUpload($ad_imgs_news);
            var_dump($ad_imgs_news);
        }
}
```

the news model

the get Last news id inserted ;

```
    public function getLastNewsId()
    {
      $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
      return $last_id;
    }
```

the upload inset method in upload model

```
    public function addUpload($data)
    {
      // $this->db->set('name', $name);
      $this->db->insert('upload', $data);
    }
```

So where the problem are in db or in code or??? 

Thanks,
 Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to return

```
$last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

from

```
$this->newsModel->addNews($ad_ne_data);
```

Get the insert_id immediately after the query in `addNews` function.

Comment: With pleasure. Always happy to help.